# Why picture viewers crash when open a not very large file?

Tags: ubuntu, images, crash

I use this command create a QR code:

```
$ yes 1 | head -c 1000 | qrencode -s 100 -o qr.png
```

The size of `qr.png` is not very large.

```
$ ls -lh qr.png 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kev kev 251K May  9 14:51 qr.png
```

When I opened it with `ImagicMagick display`, `The GNOME image viewer`, `Shotwell photo viewer`, they all crashed.

I want to know what make this image so special.

[image]

Comment: Could you please upload it and add it to your post? *cough*

Comment: Doesn't crash on my Mac. `md5sum` of the image file is `f8ace389be96a58924de847ebe6df974`.

Comment: It's probably because the image is 128 megapixels, despite the tiny file size, and your image viewers do something stupid, like allocating memory based on dimensions.

Comment: But firefox can display it without a problem.

Comment: @kev: firefox renders things completely differently than an image viewer would

Comment: @madmaze: [citation needed] regarding rendering of a PNG image to screen

Comment: It slows down my Google Chrome session quite a bit.